# How to fix TypeScript errors when using Vuex mapGetters?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

When using `mapGetters`, TypeScript has no visibility into what the getters being bound to the Vue component, so it throws errors. Example:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

export default Vue.extend({
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('ui', ['navCollapsed']),

    minimizerIconClass(): string {
      return `fa${this.navCollapsed ? '' : 'r'} fa-window-maximize`;
    },
  },
```

TypeScript is yelling about `this.navCollapsed`:

```
TS2339: Property 'navCollapsed' does not exist on type 'CombinedVueInstance<Vue, {}, { openMobileMenu(): void; }, { minimizerIconClass: string; }, Readon...'.
```

How do I fix this? The only workaround I can come up with is to not use `mapGetters()`.

Comment: You can use fake `this` parameter: `minimizerIconClass(this: ComponentTypeHere)`. (It exists only at compile time and stripped out during compilation)

Comment: What's an example of what `ComponentTypeHere` would be? (sorry, pretty new to TypeScript)

Comment: It could be just `{ navCollapsed: boolean }` in this specific example. (Need more info, not sure where `navCollapsed` comes from)

Comment: `navCollapsed` is being injected by `mapGetters()`.

Comment: @ffxsam Did you find a way to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend using  [vuex-class](https://github.com/ktsn/vuex-class) for decorators with Typescript.

But if you don't want the extra dependency, I believe using `this['navCollapsed']` instead of `this.navCollapsed` should resolve the compilation error.

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem and did the following:

```
declare module "vuex" {
    interface TMapGetters {
        <TGetters>(getterNames: Array<keyof TGetters>): Partial<TGetters>;
    }

    export const mapGetters: TMapGetters;
}
```

Then in my store I define:

```
interface TGetters {
    navCollapsed: boolean;
}
```

Now in my component I can do:

```
type TThis = TGetters & TData & TMethods & TComputed & TProps;

export default Vue.extend<TData, TMethods, TComputed, TProps>({
    computed: {
        ...mapGetters<TGetters>([
            'navCollapsed',
        ],
        minimizerIconClass(this: TThis): string {
            return `fa${this.navCollapsed ? '' : 'r'} fa-window-maximize`;
        }
    }
}
```

Far from perfect, but it will detect typos in the array passed to `mapGetters` and it will allow you to use your (correctly typed) getter on `this`.

However, TypeScript will not know whether you actually did map the getter in question or not.

Comment: Hello, can you give a full implementation of this solution ? I don't figure out the definition of TMethods, TComputed, TData and TProps.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the mapGetters was outside of the computed.
Putting it in there solved the error.